# Missing StoreKit APIs in in-app purchases

Tags: xamarin.forms, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have implemented successfully on android in app billing in my Xamarin forms application, however on iOS I am having some issues.

This is displayed with my in-app purchases :

"These in-app purchases or subscriptions can't be promoted on the App Store because your latest approved binary doesn’t include the required StoreKit APIs."

I had a look and it seems that the package does include StoreKit APIs . I have plugin version 7.05 and now I upgraded to 7.10 and I have the same issue